# Django Python email validations no shared email between multiple users

Tags: python, django, validation

I am needing to know what code I need to put into my models.py (validations) so that when  a user goes to register for a new account, that if they input a value into the email field that is already in the Data Base, that they get an error.

class UserManager(models.Manager):
def user_registration_validator(self, post_data):
errors = {}
EMAIL_REGEX = re.compile(r'^[a-zA-Z0-9.+*-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.*-]+.[a-zA-Z]+$')

```
    if len(post_data['first_name']) < 3:
        errors['first_name'] = "First name must be 3 characters"

    if post_data['first_name'].isalpha() == False:
        errors['first_name'] = "letters only"

    if len(post_data['last_name']) < 3:
        errors['last_name'] = "Last name must be 3 characters"

    if post_data['last_name'].isalpha() == False:
        errors['last_name'] = "letters only"

    if len(post_data['email']) < 8:
        errors['email'] = "Email must contain 8 characters"
    
    #if post_data['email'].Books.objects.filter(title=post_data) == True:
       # errors['email'] ="this email already exist in database"

    if post_data['email'].find("@") == -1:
        errors['email'] = "email must contain @ and .com"

    if post_data['email'].find(".com") == -1:
        errors['email'] = "email must contain @ and .com"
    
    # test whether a field matches the pattern
    if not EMAIL_REGEX.match(post_data['email']):
        errors['email'] = "Invalid email address!"

    if post_data['password'] != post_data['confirm_password']:
        errors['pass_match'] = "password must match confirm password"

    if len(post_data['password']) < 8:
        errors['pass_length'] = "password must be longer than 8 characters"

    return errors
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? How does your code look like?

Comment: if post_data['email'].Books.objects.filter(title=post_data) == True:
            #errors['email'] ="this email already exist in database"
this is something I tired and it didn't worked

Comment: please edit your question and add the code there. It might be worth adding ALL relevant code, i.e. the model, the view and even the relevant part of the template.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#emailfield Set `unique` to True. see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#unique

Comment: I went ahead and posted my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your model add a field that looks like this:

```
user_email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
```

Comment: If that works out for you please accept the answer.